# How to test AJAX Callback with simpletest on Drupal 6

Tags: 6, ajax, testing

I know there is **drupalPostAJAX()** available on Drupal 7 to do this, but I want to use it on Drupal 6.
So I found on this link : http://tiger-fish.com/blog/drupal-6-posting-ajax-callbacks-simpletest a way that should normally make it to work, but no success.

Or maybe I'm not using it as it does.

First of all, I'm using **drupalGet()** to go on the URL, then I've only one textfield whose send the value (name_search) to the callback by clicking on a "Search" button.
How can I check now, the result return by the callback that's displaying via AJAX ?